# Purging log files using EntLib

Tags: enterprise-library

Does anyone know how to set EntLib in order to purge the log files generated by the rolling flat file trace listener?

I've seen the "MaximumLogFilesBeforePurge" option in a tutorial for entlib 2.0 but it seems it is not there anymore in 4.1

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The [Rolling Flat File Trace Listener in Enterprise Library 5.0](http://entlib.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=EntLib5Beta1ChangeLog&referringTitle=EntLib5%20Beta1#lab) now has an additional property that enables you to specify the number of log files to keep, and can automatically purge older files based on this setting.